# How to assign variables to tkinter buttons, to pass to a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a script in tkinter that will have an unknown number of buttons, generated from a list. I would like these buttons to pass the list item that created it to a function. In my code below, all buttons pass the same (last) list item. Can anyone please help me get this to work?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def grid_cycle(b):
    print(b)

items = [6,3,5,4]

for x in items:
        
    Button(root, text="x", command=lambda *args: grid_cycle(x)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the partial function (my recommendation):

```
from functools import partial
for x in items:
    Button(root, text=x, command=partial(grid_cycle, x)).pack()
```

Another common way is to abuse the default arguments for lambda:

```
for x in items:
    Button(root, text=x, command=lambda x=x: grid_cycle(x)).pack()
```

Comment: Much appreciated!! I'm still getting the hand of this.